# Is it possible to migrate Oracle SOA BPEL instances from one environment to another with history

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

Is it possible to migrate Oracle SOA BPEL instances from one environment to another with history? For instance, I want to move from BPEL instances deployed to defined partition on Oracle SOA to another environment. How it can be done?

Comment: _Instances_ in Oracle SOA world are BPEL composites that are running or have already been executed so they can't be moved (well, I guess the database entries can be but they won't make sense in the context of your other environment).  Rather, do you mean you wish to move the composites themselves to another environment, and preserve their history?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm talking about moving the composites to another environment and preserve their history.

Comment: You'd be better off looking into replicating rather than moving.